# Better practice for identifying what part of state to change when having one event handler for multiple dynamically created fields?

Tags: reactjs

In React, callback functions are often used to send a signal from a child to a parent that something has happened.

I am building an application where the user is able to dynamically create more fields, and all change events for all fields are served by the same callback function. See my code below. As you can see I am using `event`, `name`, and `key` to know what part of my state to change.

Editable component passes name to parent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Editable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this)
  }

  onBlur(event) {
    this.props.handleBlur(event, this.props.name)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          contentEditable={true}
          onBlur={this.onBlur}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.html }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Subject component passes name and id to parent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Editable from "./Editable";
export default class Subject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
  }

  handleBlur(event, name) {
    this.props.handleBlur(event, name, this.props.skillId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>subject</p>
        <Editable
          handleBlur={this.handleBlur}
          html={this.props.subject}
          name="subject"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The callback in the parent has the callback it needs to update the correct skill[property] in the state.

```
import Skill from "./Skill";

export default class Skills extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
  }

  handleBlur(event, name, key) {
    // Shange the state
  }

  render() {
    var skills = [];
    this.props.skills.map(element => {
      skills.push(
        <Skill
          key={element.id}
          skillId={element.id}
          subject={element.subject}
          ability={element.ability}
          handleBlur={this.props.handleBlur}
        />
      );
    });
    return <div>{skills}</div>;
  }
}
```

What is a better practice for identifying what part of state to change when having one event handler for multiple dynamically created fields?

Comment: I think its better to just create different eventhandlers for different parts of the state, but if someone has a better option I would love to hear it.